# Drag and drop a snapshot of a canvas element to a video element

Tags: javascript, html

The video player should go back to the
playback time when the user took the last snapshot, when the user drags the
snapshot image in the canvas and drops it onto the video player. If the video
player is playing the video when the drag&drop happens, the video player
should start playing from the playback time when the snapshot was taken.
My screenshot works fine, but I when I drop the screenshot to the video element, I can't take it back to the time. My code is as follow

```
var can = document.getElementById("capture");
    // Get a handle on the 2d context of the canvas element
var canvas = document.getElementById("screenshot");
var context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    // Define some vars required later
var tm=document.getElementById("t");

// Add a listener to wait for the 'loadedmetadata' state so the video's dimensions can be read
    can.addEventListener("click", function() {

     capturedTime=video.currentTime.toFixed(1);
        tm.innerHTML="snapshot is taken at " +capturedTime+ "secs";
                     context.drawImage(video, 0, 0, 350, 150);
    },false);

    canvas.addEventListener("dragstart", function(ev){
    capturedTime=video.currentTime.toFixed(1);
    ev.dataTransfer.setData("time",capturedTime);
    },false);
   video.addEventListener("dragover",function(ev){
   ev.preventDefault();
    },false);
   video.addEventListener("ondrop",function(ev){
     ev.preventDefault();
                            video.currentTime=ev.dataTransfer.getData("time");

 },false);
```

Comment: Your code does not reflect your story, it attempts to set the video back to where it was when you started dragging the image, instead of where it was when the snapshot was taken.